# Django-Celery - How to know when a subtask has been completed?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm using Django-Celery-Email. This app will send a task to send an e-mail with the regular "from django.core.mail import send_mail".

I have wrote a task that will call the send_mail task, but I need to when when the subtask is done to do an update in the database.

This is my tasks.py

```
from celery import task


@task()
def send_ad_contact_email():
    from django.core.mail import send_mail

    # Send the e.mail
    send_mail('test subject', 'Here is the message.', 'somemail@gmail.com',
        ['tosomemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

    # Update the email status on the model
    # How can I know when send_mail(celery task) is done?
```

How can I know when send_mail(celery task) is done?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use a chord.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html?highlight=taskset#chords

Answer (score 0):

```
task_id = request.GET['task_id']
res = AsyncResult(task_id)
result = res.result
```

more info [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html)